# EA Model Validation Error

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

1. We have developed the Model Validation Rules(approximately 80 validation rules) for the EA.Elements and EA.Connectors through AddIn. When we are trying to run the validation rules from the menu Package->Model Validation->Validate Current Package, more than twice or after validating the Model if we try to add few more elements from the toolbox then EA.exe is exiting  with the error message “UML has stopped working”. 
   Please refer the images.
   [image: UML Error]
   [image: Addin Error]

   public ModelValidationRules theRules;

   public virtual void EA_OnInitializeUserRules(EA.Repository Repository)
   {
       if (Repository != null)
       {
           theRules = new ModelValidationRules();

   ```
       theRules.ConfigureCategories(Repository);

       theRules.ConfigureRules(Repository);
   }
   ```

   }

   public void EA_OnRunElementRule(EA.Repository Repository, string RuleID,    EA.Element element)
   {
       theRules.RunElementRule(Repository, RuleID, element);
   }
2. When I am running my Addin in Debug Mode then I am getting "Unhandled Exception" error as shown in the below figure.

[image: Unhandled Exception Error]
[image: Wntdll.pbd not loaded]

Comment: Well, correct the error and you're done.

Comment: If I run the Model Validation Rules for 1st time then its validation the Model correctly, this problem is only occurring when I try to add new Element into EA or I am running the Validation rules more than 2 times.

Comment: Unfortunately the clairvoyants on SO are already on skiing holiday. So posting the part of your code that fails would likely help solving your problem.

Comment: @ Thomas Kilian- Please refer my post for code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code you posted. This is just the way EA reports the error, which probably happened somewhere deeper in your code.

In case of an error involving an add-in debug your code by attaching your IDE to the ea.exe process and let it break on any exceptions.

Comment: - Geert: I have updated the comments. Please refer it.

Comment: You have now posted some images that don't really help us. You just need to break at the exception, step through the code and fix the problem. That is not something we can, or are willing to do for you (especially since we don't have your code)